# Как транспонировать DataFrame и создать новый индекс (столбец)?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

Есть такой DataFrame:

```
   Id      Level1   Level2   Level3   Level4
0  EURUSD  1.19507  1.18701  1.20012  1.20892


Ожидаемый результат такой:

index  Id         EURUSD     
0      Level1     1.19507  
1      Level2     1.18701  
2      Level3     1.20012  
3      Level4     1.20892
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Еще один вариант:

```
res = df.set_index("Id").T.reset_index()
```

результат:

```
In [65]: res
Out[65]:
Id   index   EURUSD
0   Level1  1.19507
1   Level2  1.18701
2   Level3  1.20012
3   Level4  1.20892
```

---

Или так, чтобы установить правильные наименования столбцов:

```
res = (df
       .set_index("Id")
       .T
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
       .reset_index()
       .rename(columns={"index": "Id"}))
```

результат:

```
In [85]: res
Out[85]:
       Id   EURUSD
0  Level1  1.19507
1  Level2  1.18701
2  Level3  1.20012
3  Level4  1.20892
```

Comment: Ого одной строкой :)  Большущее ВАМ !!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Я сделал, но как-то сложновато получилось, наверняка можно проще:

```
import pandas as pd

cols = 'Id      Level1   Level2   Level3   Level4'.split()
vals = 'EURUSD  1.19507  1.18701  1.20012  1.20892'.split()

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(cols,vals)), index=[0])
df = df.T.reset_index()
df_cols = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
df.columns = df_cols
df
```

Вывод:

```
    Id  EURUSD
1   Level1  1.19507
2   Level2  1.18701
3   Level3  1.20012
4   Level4  1.20892
```

И индексация получилась с 1 при этом. Если хочется с 0, то нужно добавить `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Спасибо Вам !!!